# How to pay a higher fee in solana.js

Tags: web3.js

Is there an example on how to voluntarily pay a higher fee when creating and sending a transaction in solana js (for the recent quic changes)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code, first normal tx and then priority fee

I do not understand too much about units how influx in the overall tx but you can add additional fee to the tx. And the additional fee instruction must be the first of all instructions in the tx.

Reference : [solanacookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-change-compute-budget-for-a-transaction)

```
import * as anchor from '@project-serum/anchor';

const conn = new anchor.web3.Connection('https://api.devnet.solana.com', 'confirmed');
const wallet = new anchor.web3.Keypair();
let airdrop = await conn.requestAirdrop(wallet.publicKey, 1e9);
const to = new anchor.web3.PublicKey('ANY PUB KEY');

// normal tx
let tx1 = new anchor.web3.Transaction()
    .add(anchor.web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
        toPubkey: to,
        lamports:1000
    }))

let sig1 = await conn.sendTransaction(tx1, [wallet]);

// priority fee
const priorityFee = anchor.web3.ComputeBudgetProgram.requestUnits({
    units:400000,
    additionalFee:1000,
});

let tx2 = new anchor.web3.Transaction()
    .add(priorityFee)
    .add(anchor.web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
        toPubkey: to,
        lamports:1000
    }))

let sig2 = await conn.sendTransaction(tx2, [wallet]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the appropriate [`ComputeBudget` program instruction](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/ComputeBudgetProgram.html#setComputeUnitPrice) which unfortunately is not well documented in the JS docs, but you can read about it in the [`solana-sdk` crate rustdocs](https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/latest/solana_sdk/compute_budget/enum.ComputeBudgetInstruction.html#variant.SetComputeUnitPrice)